# MySQL exclusive lock (FOR UPDATE) is locking the whole table

Tags: mysql, multithreading, concurrency, locking, innodb

I have a MySQL table (using InnoDB as a storage engine) to store user transactions.

```
CREATE TABLE `transactions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `correlation_id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `currency` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `time_created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `transaction_amount` double NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `transactions`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `correlation_id_unique` (`correlation_id`), 
  ADD INDEX (`user_id`);
```

I'd working in a multithreading environment and want to make sure that:

- No two threads can insert transactions for the same user concurrently
- If a thread is inserting a transaction for a user, no other thread can read transactions from that user

I came up with the following solution:

1. When a thread wants to insert a transaction for a user, acquire an exclusive lock for rows corresponding to this user

   ```
   BEGIN;

   -- Acquire an exclusive lock on the rows with user_id=1
   SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE user_id = 1 FOR UPDATE;

   -- Insert transactions
   ...

   COMMIT;
   ```
2. When a threads wants to read a user balance (typically by summing over all the transactions of a user), it first acquires a shared lock for rows corresponding to this user

   ```
   SELECT SUM(transaction_amount) 
   FROM transactions 
   WHERE user_id=1 
   LOCK IN SHARE MODE;
   ```

**However, it seems that the exclusive lock is locking the whole table** and not only the rows returned by the SELECT... FOR UPDATE statement. Here's an example.

Thread 1:

```
mysql> select user_id, transaction_amount from transactions;
+---------+--------------------+
| user_id | transaction_amount |
+---------+--------------------+
| 1       |                 10 |
| 1       |                 -2 |
| 2       |                  5 |
| 2       |                 10 |
+---------+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> BEGIN;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE user_id = 1 FOR UPDATE;
+----+----------------+---------+----------+---------------------+--------------------+
| id | correlation_id | user_id | currency | time_created        | transaction_amount |
+----+----------------+---------+----------+---------------------+--------------------+
|  1 | 1              | 1       | CHF      | 2018-03-06 09:54:28 |                 10 |
|  2 | 2              | 1       | CHF      | 2018-03-06 09:54:28 |                 -2 |
+----+----------------+---------+----------+---------------------+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Thread 2:

```
-- Retrieve transactions of user 2
mysql> SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE user_id = 2 LOCK IN SHARE MODE;

[[Hangs]]
```

After reading [MySQL's documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html), I would have expected this to work:

> SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE
>
> Sets a shared mode lock on any rows that are read. **Other sessions can read the rows**, but cannot modify them until your transaction commits
>
> SELECT ... FOR UPDATE
>
> For index records the search encounters, locks the rows and any associated index entries, the same as if you issued an UPDATE statement for those rows. Other transactions are blocked from updating **those rows**, from doing SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE, or from reading the data in certain transaction isolation levels.

Now, I found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37493222/lock-in-share-mode-locks-entire-table), stating that in my case, the `user_id` field should have an index - and it does.

I have a feeling the problem might be caused by the request `SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE user_id=1` not making use of the index:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE user_id=1 FOR UPDATE;
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table        | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | transactions | NULL       | ALL  | user_id       | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    2 |    50.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 3 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your table with MySQL 5.6.31, and filled it with half a million rows of random values between 1 and 1000.

Even forcing the index didn't help:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `transactions` force index (user_id) where user_id=1;
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | transactions | ALL  | user_id       | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 520674 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
```

But searching for a string of the integer works, even without an index hint:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `transactions`  where user_id='1';
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | transactions | ref  | user_id       | user_id | 36      | const |    1 | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-----------------------+
```

The comparison of the varchar column to a binary integer seems to defeat indexability.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much!